# In Excel: How can I get a count of the number of times a specific keyword appears in a list of long-string comments?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 1998 comments from a user survey on features users want to see. I have seen some patterns just by scanning the document. I basically would like a Cntrl-F feature that allows me to scan for multiple words that are related, and then give me a count.

For example, users have said they want to find a doctor. I want to search for "doctor", "PCP", "provider", "specialist"... and then have it return a count of how many comments contained these words.

Can this be done, or would it look for comments that contained ALL of these words? I thought COUNTIF would do it, but it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you tried and where the problem is? Did you tried `Countif()` with wildcard like `=COUNTIF(A1:A3,"*doctor*")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one or two steps.

Two steps:

1. Count how many comments contain each of the related words.
2. Sum above.

Let `comments` be the range of all the comments and `keyword` the cell for each keyword. The formula next to each related word would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(keyword, comments))))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYLdv.png)

**OR**

One step:

Let `comments` be the range of all the comments and `keywords` the range of the keywords. The formula would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(comments, "*" & keywords & "*"))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2LfH.png)